# postgresql insert a null convert to default?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, hibernate

There are some features in MySQL but not in postgresql.
1.create a table and give a column default value
2.insert a null value to the table.
In MySQL it will insert the default value;
In postgresql it will insert the null value;
How can I make postgresql do the same like MySQL.
I found this problem during change DBMS.My app is code in java.
ORM is Hibernate 5.1.0.
I change the DBMS then a lots of default column is not work.

MySQL sql

```
drop table table1;
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  column_1 int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  column_2 timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp
);
insert into table1(column_2) values(null);
select * from table1;
```

result

```
| column_1 | column_2            |
+----------+---------------------+
|        1 | 2018-04-24 10:00:18 |
```

pgsql

```
drop table table2;
CREATE TABLE table2
(
column_1 serial PRIMARY KEY,
column_2 timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp
);
insert into table2(column_2) values (null);
select * from table2;
```

result

```
 column_1 | column_2 
----------+----------
        1 |
```

Comment: If you really want this, you could use a trigger. Personally I would rather say “MySQL has a misfeature that will let you shoot yourself in the leg” rather than say PostgreSQL is missing a feature. If I say “put NULL here” and the DBMS doesn’t do that, it’s a problem in my book. Best would be to not include it in the insert at all

Answer (score 6):

I think if you want to get default value when insert I suggest you 3 ways:

1. Don't put it in your query.
2. Use the keyword `DEFAULT` AS `insert into table2(column_2) values (DEFAULT);`
3. Write a trigger and process the data when you insert.

Hopefully my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This will insert null.

```
test=# insert into table2(column_2) values (null);
INSERT 0 1
test=# select * from table2;
 column_1 | column_2 
----------+----------
        1 | [null]
(1 row)
```

While inserting and not including the column with the default value will insert its default. I guess you have a sequence you can use for this.

```
test=# insert into table2(column_1) select max(column_1)+1 from table2;
INSERT 0 1
test=# select * from table2;
 column_1 |          column_2          
----------+----------------------------
        1 | [null]
        2 | 2018-04-24 03:44:10.669642
(2 rows)
```